# Jquery datepicker does not show current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have datepicker in my page. It work's fine. But my problem is that it shows '01/01/2001' as default date. It should shows '11/23/2012' now!
My jquery code is:

```
        $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
```

What is problem with my code?

This is whole code of file:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(
        function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
        }
    );
    //$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["en-GB"]);
    $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker({defaultDate: 0});

}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LbyJt/) is a sample code...
It works fine by itself. Default date is 11/23/2012, also if you want you can move your default date to any date or explicitly define it like this: `$(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker({ defaultDate: 0 });`.
Maybe you made some mistake using jQuery UI API, so your code broke?

EDIT: You can maybe try this: `$("#datepick").datepicker({setDate: new Date()});`

Comment: Unfortunately not works. I use jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js API in MVC Web Application.

Comment: The only explanation is that you have an error somewhere in your JS. Have you tried debugging it with Firebug or Chrome Developer tools?

Comment: I didn't find any error in my code. I added whole file code to my question.

Comment: I edited my answer with some code. You can try it. Also make sure that you are using the newest jQuery UI library.

Comment: I tested with newest version, but it doesn't work!
Unfortunately your edited code does not work!

Comment: Is there any way i set defaultDate to some date like: '11/23/2012'??

Comment: You can create a new Javascript date object like this `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` and put it in last line in my answer like this: `$("#datepick").datepicker({setDate: new Date(2012, 10, 23));`.  You have to keep in mind that for some reason, month has to be `month-1`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work! Are you sure localization isn't problem here?

Comment: Unfortunately, if I don't see your code I can't help you. It's pretty simple usually to get this plugin to work. I showed it to you in a link that I put in my response above. It's one line of code and it works. It means that you made some mistake somewhere else probably. Sry I couldn't help you further.

Comment: Thank you. I tested my datepicker in one html page. It works fine. I don't understand why it does not work in MVC cshtml file!
Appreciate your trying.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the localization on the constuctor function.

See [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) page for more information.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in details?

Comment: I don't think localization is the problem here.